# How to change mouse sensivity and mouse acceleration in I3 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mouse

i want to change my mousespeed and acceration drivers. My openrazer drivers do not work so i try:

```
xinput --list --short
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3064:00 06CB:8265 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3064:00 06CB:8265 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Tournament Edition Consumer Control id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Tournament Edition      id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Chroma Consumer Control    id=23   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Chroma             id=28   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SteelSeries SteelSeries Arctis 1 Wireless Consumer Control    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Tournament Edition Consumer Control id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Tournament Edition      id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Tournament Edition System Control   id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Tournament Edition Keyboard id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Chroma Consumer Control    id=24   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Chroma Keyboard    id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Chroma             id=26   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Chroma System Control  id=27   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What to choose now, which id is the right one and if i have chosen the right id, what exactly is responsible for mouse accerelation and which option for mouse speed? what is an accerelation profile?

Comment: Check the documentation of `synclient`.

Comment: i want to change my mouse accerelation

Comment: Searching 'mouse acceleration' in AskUbuntu returns 484 results...  please help yourself.

Comment: Open ubuntu settings, and click "mouse & touchpad" in the sidebar.

Comment: Sorry `synclient` seems to concern only Synaptics touchpad.  Mouse & touchpad only has a speed setting.  I found this link instructive : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mouse_acceleration

Comment: `dconf-editor` has /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/accel-profile parameter.

Comment: See also Activities > Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Mouse accelaration profile.